# How to loop through a table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have a table that I need to dynamically add data to and the amount of columns needed will depend on how many service providers there are.  I am wanting to loop through the tr and td of the table but for now I am just trying to add a forEach statement within the table but I get this error: Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this using React or Lodash?

```
          <table className='table-body'>
            <tbody>
              {
                forEach(leadServiceProviderComparison.response.assignedServiceProviders, (provider) => {
                  console.log('provider: ', provider);
                })
              }
              <tr style={{height: '65px'}}>
                  <th>Gatlin Plumbing &#38; Heatings</th>
                  <th>St. John Plumbing, Inc.</th>
                  <th>Budget Right Handyman</th>
                  <th>Plumbing Company</th>
              </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? Do you have a hardcoded array in your program? Are you pulling from a database? API?

Comment: You should never had to loop through markup in react, it should be data driven. Meaning you should loop through a data set to render markup.

Comment: I don't know React very well, but from what I know of, there's no global `forEach` function. You have to call it on your array, or your lodash imported variable.

Comment: I agree with Isaac. If you are pulling from a database or an API, you will likely need to convert from JSON to read it. If it is a hardcoded array, you can just loop directly over it. Then you can use `map` or `forEach` to create multiple copies of a component called `Provider` or something.

Comment: It is a hard coded json file that we are using as fake data for the time being.  I am trying to loop through a data set to render the tr(s) and td(s) of the table.  I added an image to my question to show that it is logging the providers just fine.  It is able to loop through the data set with forEach and output the logs but its this error of "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys" that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `forEach` like that.
If you want to loop through an array of stuff you got from your data API then try using `map`.

`Map` is supported on all arrays and you don't need Lodash for this.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html for examples.

Answer (score -1):

Inside `tbody`:

```
    {
              leadServiceProviderComparison.response.assignedServiceProviders.map((provider,index)=>return(
                 <tr key={index} style={{height: '65px'}}>
                      <th>Gatlin Plumbing &#38; Heatings</th>
                      <th>St. John Plumbing, Inc.</th>
                      <th>Budget Right Handyman</th>
                      <th>Plumbing Company</th>
                  </tr>
);)
    }
```

Comment: FWIW, indexes are discouraged as keys. And ‘return’ keyword is superfluous since you are wrapping the whole thing in curly braces (arrow functions retun implicitly).